# Example to prove that $C_c(\mathbb{N})$ is not a Banach space for the uniform norm?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I know The space $(C_c(\mathbb{R}), \lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_u)$ is not complete, so it is not a Banach space. But for $X = \mathbb{N}$, why is $C_c(X)$ not a Banach space?
Can a sequence of functions with compact supports converge to a function which is nonzero on all of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @b.balal if the compact support gets 'wider', then the limit function need not have compact support

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$x_n =\left( 1 +\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{n} ,...,\frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n} ,0,0,...\right)$$